# Launch activity using custom intent throwing ACTIVITY NOT FOUND EXCEPTION

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am using the below code to launch the activity form my application:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.android.excample.cutstom_action");
intent.setData(data); //public Uri data
intent.putExtra(Intent.Extra_stream, stream); // public Uri stream
startActivity(intent);
```

And in the other application the activity is defined in manifest file as follow:

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.android.excample.cutstom_action"/>
<category android:name = "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

but when i try to start the activity i am getting activity not found exception.
please help me to solve this issue

the crash log is as follow:
"`03-04 20:03:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22633): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
03-04 20:03:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22633): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/51826 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.test/com.example.test.ContentPickerTester}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.android.excample.cutstom_action } 
03-04 20:03:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22633):         at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2983) 
03-04 20:03:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22633):         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3026) 
03-04 20:03:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22633):         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:126) 
03-04 20:03:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22633):         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1180) 
03-04 20:03:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22633):         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
03-04 20:03:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22633):         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
03-04 20:03:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22633):         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4456) 
03-04 20:03:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22633):         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
03-04 20:03:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22633):         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
03-04 20:03:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22633):         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787) 
03-04 20:03:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22633):         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554) 
03-04 20:03:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22633):         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
03-04 20:03:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22633): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.android.excample.cutstom_action } 
03-04 20:03:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22633):         at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1512) 
03-04 20:03:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22633):         at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384) 
03-04 20:03:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22633):         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190) 
03-04 20:03:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22633):         at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297) 
03-04 20:03:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22633):         at com.example.test.ContentPickerTester.onActivityResult(ContentPickerTester.java:64) 
03-04 20:03:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22633):         at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4649) 
03-04 20:03:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22633):         at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2979)`"

Comment: Post the logcat. And make sure you've positioned the `<activity>` element correctly in the manifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set "." before the name of your activity in the manifast file

```
".MyActivity"
```

or set it with the full qualified path like so:

```
"com.android.excample.MyActivity"
```

Comment: i have already added it forgot to put it while posting in the site

Comment: @user2089918 Also set a matching mimetype in the intent.

Comment: well thanks for the help @User117 : ) looks like you were right.

Comment: @user2089918 what will be the mimetype?